# Checking which browser is being used

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I am using `DefaultSelenium` and want to know which browser was being used. My project is set up so that there is a base class that provides a number of convenience methods and protected variables, and all scripts inherit from this base class and implement the macro logic that I call "plugins".

Due to differences in different browsers, I may need to perform steps a little differently (for example, firefox doesn't have the `event` javascript object that google chrome does)

Currently, all of these plugins instantiate the browser like this

```
browser = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox",homePage);
```

I am suggesting to change this to something like

```
browser = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444, browserType ,homePage);
```

Where `browserType` is a string that is one of the supported browsers. However if there was an easy way to just access this information that would be convenient. I have not found anything in the docs to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't think I am using webdriver. Unless you are suggesting to change what I am using.